# How do I use the Taylor series to calculate $\ln(4)$ with an error of $10^{-5}$ with no calculator?

Tags: derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am aware of the Taylor series of $\ln(1+x)$, but this isn't a Maclaurin series. Do I just need to use a normal Taylor series and derive $\ln(1+x)$ multiple times with $a=e$?

Comment: I'd have thought that $a=e-1$ would be a more straightforward choice

Comment: Tangential remark: Actually, the series you're probably thinking of (the usual series for $\ln(1 + x)$) **is** a Maclaurin series, simply because it's a Taylor series centred at $0$ (i.e. the power series contains powers of $x$, rather than $x - a$ for some $a \neq 0$). This series is just a shifting of the Taylor series for $\ln(x)$ at $a = 1$ (so, not a Maclaurin series), which we do for a couple of reasons, one of which being that it's just cleaner to present a power series centred at $0$.

Answer (score 4):

You could use the fact that $\ln(4)=-2\ln(0.5)$, and approximate $\ln(1-0.5)$ using the Taylor series.

Answer (score 1):

@Especially Lime gave a good trick
$$\log(4)=-2 \log \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)$$ Let us continue writing that
$$\frac{1}{2}=\frac{1-\frac{1}{3}}{1+\frac{1}{3}}$$ and now, use the fast convergent expansion
$$\log \left(\frac{1+x}{1-x}\right)=2\Bigg[\frac {x}1+\frac {x^3}3+\frac {x^5}5+\frac {x^7}7 +\frac {x^9}9 +\cdots\Bigg]$$ So, by hand, the quantity in brackets is
$$-\frac {1}3-\frac{1}{81}-\frac{1}{1215}-\frac{1}{15309}-\frac{1}{177147}$$ which is more than enough for an error of $10^{-5}$.

So, we have
$$\log(4) \sim -2 \times 2 \Bigg[-\frac {1}3-\frac{1}{81}-\frac{1}{1215}-\frac{1}{15309}-\frac{1}{177147}\Bigg]=\frac{8595212}{6200145}=1.3862921$$ while the exact value is $1.3862944$ corresponding to an error of $2.27\times 10^{-6}$.

Ignoring the last term would not be sufficient.